# C# RSACryptoServiceProvider export key as SPKI/DER

Tags: c#, cryptography

I want to have the equivalent to this javascript code

```
const rsaKeyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 2048
});
const publicKey = rsaKeyPair.publicKey.export({
    type: 'spki',
    format: 'der'
});
```

but i am unable to found documentation on SPKI.
I never did cryptography in C# i don't know if it's even possible or if there is a way to transform another type of key into it.
I currently have this code :

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
byte[] publicKey = rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey();
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(publicKey));
```

Comment: The NodeJS code exports the RSA public key in X.509/SPKI format, DER encoded. As of .NET Core 3.0 there is [`ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.exportsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=net-6.0), which applies the same format and encoding. In versions where this method is not available, BouncyCastle/C# is an alternative. The method `ExportRSAPublicKey()` you are using exports the public key in PKCS#1 format.

Comment: Don’t use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` if you can help it. Just use `RSA.Create(2048)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks i managed to do it with `RSA.Create(2048)` and `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`

```
RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
rsa.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
```